# Finding the biggest among multiple variables

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have four variables `$a`, `$b`, `$c` and `$d`. They each have an integer value assigned to them. I need to find the *variable* with the highest value (Not the value itself). This is what I tried :

```
// $a, $b, $c, $d are initialized with values here

$highest_value = max($a,$b,$c,$d);
if($a==$highest_value){$biggest_variable = 'a'};
if($b==$highest_value){$biggest_variable = 'b'};
if($c==$highest_value){$biggest_variable = 'c'};
if($d==$highest_value){$biggest_variable = 'd'};
```

While not very efficient, it gets the job done.  But this falls flat if any of the variables are equal in value. This seemingly simple problem has me stumped! Is there any simpler solution than manually comparing each variable to check if any are equal?

EDIT : Okay so, the reason for sorting is for scoring. Each variable constitutes a Team. Scores are calculated as :

`Winning Team = 1,000,000 / Value , Other Teams = 200,000 / Value`

So with `a` = 10 and rest having values `3,4,5` for `b,c,d`, Score for a is `1,000,000 / 10`, Rest would be `200,000` divided by their respective values.

Comment: Well is there a logic that should be followed when 2 values are both the highest?

Comment: what behavior would you expect with equal values ? (this question and its multiplie answers actually being the reason why no builtin way of handling this exists)

Comment: what happen if there are two highest value??

Comment: So what has your edit to do with the original question? Do you want to sort your variables by score?

Comment: Edit was only put in to answer the second comment to this question :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an array which you can use to look up the name. Then just use `max()` as before with the created array and to get the names use [`array_keys()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php), e.g.

```
<?php

    $a = 4;
    $b = 7;
    $c = 2;
    $d = 1;

    $arr = ["a" => $a, "b" => $b, "c" => $c, "d" => $d];

    print_r(array_keys($arr, max($arr)));

?>
```

output:

```
Array(
    [0] => b
)
```

Comment: I think `rsort` is been better if two variables have a same number anyways +1

Comment: @Uchiha When two variables would have the same value you would have them both in the output with using `array_keys()`. If OP always just wants one value he can just change out `array_keys()` with `array_search`.

Comment: You can't assume everybody is using the latest PHP version. I would like to suggest using `array()` instead of `[..., ..., ...]`

Comment: @Peter But I hope I can assume everybody doesn't use a death [PHP version](http://php.net/supported-versions.php)

Comment: This works! I can write the rest of the logic to handle a tie. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [compact](http://php.net/manual/en/function.compact.php) to create an associative array and [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to get the key.

```
$values = compact("a", "b", "c", "d");
$highest_value = max($values);
$key = array_search($highest_value, $values);
```

As noted by others, if you had equal max values, this would only give you the first of the variables.

Comment: You want to pass the variable names, not values, to `compact()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array which you can use to look up the name. Then just use `asort()` with the created array and to get the names use `array_keys()` and `end()`, e.g.

```
<?php
// Defining a function
function getHighest($values = array())
{
    // Sorting the array
    asort($values);

    // Get the sorted array keys
    $keys = array_keys($values);

    // Return the last key
    return end($keys);
}

// Define array with values from $a, $b, $c and $d
$array = array(
    'a' => $a,
    'b' => $b,
    'c' => $c,
    'd' => $d,
);

// Pass array to getHighest()
$highest = getHighest($array);
?>
```

Comment: 1) `end()` expects an array (by reference) 2) sort() returns a bool

Comment: Fixed my answer. I was too quick in answering.

Comment: Besides the two typos (`;` missing + `arrat_keys`) you still can't pass the return value of a function by reference.

Comment: If you have [error reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) turned on: `ini_set("display_errors", 1);
 error_reporting(E_ALL);` You should get: `Notice: Only variables should be passed by reference` Because you can't pass the return value of a function [by reference](http://php.net/manual/de/language.references.pass.php). And if you look into the manual of [`end()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.end.php) then you will see, that `end()` takes the argument by reference. So you need to first assign the return value of the function to a variable, before passing to end.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$array = array
    (
    'a' => 10,
    'b' => 20,
    'c' => 15,
    'd' => 5
);

echo $highest_value = max($array);

print_r(array_keys($array,$highest_value));
```

[Phpfiddle Preview](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/hne3-vks4)